# Spark MLlib: Difference between DecisionTree.trainClassifier and DecisionTree.train

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I cannot see the difference between `DecisionTree.trainClassifier` and `DecisionTree.train` methods.

In the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/DecisionTree.scala) for `DecisionTree` there are some clues. THe comment for `train` is:

> Method to train a decision tree model.
>     The method supports binary and multiclass classification and regression.

And the comment for `trainClassifier` is:

> Method to train a decision tree model for binary or multiclass classification.

Since I would like to use binary classification, I think the best to use is the `DecisionTree.trainClassifier` method. But I would like to understand the differences.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trainClassifier` is essentially an overload of `train` where the algorithm is preset to `Classifier`

below I *** the preset `Classification` parameter in the source code you referenced

```
 def trainClassifier(
      input: RDD[LabeledPoint],
      numClasses: Int,
      categoricalFeaturesInfo: Map[Int, Int],
      impurity: String,
      maxDepth: Int,
      maxBins: Int): DecisionTreeModel = {
    val impurityType = Impurities.fromString(impurity)
    train(input, ***Classification***, impurityType, maxDepth, numClasses, maxBins, Sort,
      categoricalFeaturesInfo)
  }
```

Comment: So, is it exactly the same to use one of the other? I'm asking because I think I prefer using `def train(input: RDD[LabeledPoint], strategy: Strategy): DecisionTreeModel = {
    new DecisionTree(strategy).run(input)
}` 

I feel it more organized =)

Comment: It can be exactly the same to use train. And you can get a subset of the options if you use train Classifier. In your case you can indeed use both